# Socket.io messages returning as "null"

Tags: javascript, html, json, socket.io

I'm working on a simple chat application in socket.io and I'm currently running the files in a local server.

In my "script.js" file I have the following:

```
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000')
const messageForm = document.getElementById('send-container')
const messageInput = document.getElementById('message-input')

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
    console.log(data)
})

messageForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const message = messageInput.Value
    socket.emit('send-chat-message', message)
    messageInput.value = ''
})
```

And in my "server.js" file I have the following:

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000)

io.on('connection', socket => {
    socket.emit('chat-message', 'Hello World')
    socket.on('send-chat-message', message => {
        console.log(message)
    })
})
```

And in the html page there's a text input and a submit button, so inputting text and submitting should return the same message in my console. But instead when I submit my console will simply return "null".

I'm using this tutorial if it helps:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rxzOqP9YwmM
And using the same local connection to run the files, everything seemed to be working before. Help?

Comment: should the first `value` start with uppercase? or is it just a typo in a message? it clearly won't work this way

Comment: Syntax error, yeah, I must be tired. Thanks!